# MongooseIM connected to MySQLDB not storing anything in DB

Tags: mysql, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, mongoose-im

I have connected to to the SQL database as directions given in MongooseIM site for the SQL db linking instead of mnesia. I have made the changes in the **ejabberd.cfg** file but still I don't see any values in my DB.

However the **>mongooseimctl registered_users localhost**  command gives me the users list. How to see them in SQL and where are these stored actually.

```
%%
%% MySQL server:
%%


{odbc_server, {mysql, "localhost", 3306, "ejabberd", "root", "password123"}}.

%%
%% If you want to specify the port:
%%{odbc_server, {mysql, "server", 1234, "database", "username", "password"}}.
```

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd documentation has a full page explaining how to set it up with MySQL: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/databases/mysql/

The trick is to also make sure that the module you want to store data in MySQL are properly set to use SQL backend (for example check `auth_method`, `mod_roster`, etc)